# In WPF, can you use a Command.CanExecute to set the ToolTip?

Tags: wpf, command

This is not real code, I know. But it is what I would like to do.

```
MyBinding.CanExecute += (s, e) => 
{
    e.CanExecute = Something.Allow;
    if (!e.CanExecute)
        e.ToolTip = Something.Reason;
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: you want to be careful with this approach because CanExecute is called very frequently for all of your commands; if different CanExecute handlers/methods set ToolTip(s) to different values, you'll get very erratic behavior; using a ViewModel, you can better control when and how to set the ToolTip(s)

Comment: That's a good point.  The condition for CanExecute may just as likely be set as a by-product of setting the Reason (in the middle of some event or method) as the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way I believe to accomplish this.

This is the Command definition:

```
class CustomCommand : RoutedUICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string m_Reason;
    public string Reason
    {
        get { return m_Reason; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Reason == value)
                return;
            m_Reason = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Reason"));
        }
    }
}
public class MyCommands
{
    public static CustomCommand DoThis = new CustomCommand();
    public static CommandBinding DoThisBinding = new CommandBinding 
        { Command = DoThis };

    public static void SetupCommands()
    {
        DoThisBinding.CanExecute += (s, e) =>
        {
            var _Something = DoSomeTest(e.Parameter);
            e.CanExecute = _Something.Allow;     
            if (!e.CanExecute)         
                (e.Command as CustomCommand).Reason = _Something.Reason; 
        } 
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML implementation:

```
xmlns:commands="MyNamespace.WhereAreCommands"

<Button Command="{x:Static commands:MyCommands.DoThis}"
        ToolTip="{Binding Path=Reason, 
            Source={x:Static commands:MyCommands.DoThis}}">
    Click</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you are doing this from a ViewModel.  If so, the simplest thing to do is to have an observable "CanExecute" property for your command, and another string "Reason" property for your tooltip.

Then, you listen for the PropertyChanged event within the ViewModel.  When the CanExecute property changes, you simply update the reason.

Here is some sample code, which simply sets the CanExecute property to false when the command is executed:

```
public MyViewModel()
    : base()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "SomeCommandCanExecute")
            {
                if (mSomeCommandCanExecute)
                    this.Reason = "Some Command Can Execute";
                else
                    this.Reason = "Some Command Cannot Execute Because....";
            }
        };
}

private RelayCommand mSomeCommand = null;
private Boolean mSomeCommandCanExecute = true;
public RelayCommand SomeCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (mSomeCommand == null)
        {
            mSomeCommand = new RelayCommand(
                cmd => this.ExecuteSomeCommand(),
                cmd => this.SomeCommandCanExecute);
        }

        return mSomeCommand;
    }
}

public Boolean SomeCommandCanExecute
{
    get { return mSomeCommandCanExecute; }
    set { SetProperty("SomeCommandCanExecute", ref mSomeCommandCanExecute, value); }
}


private void ExecuteSomeCommand()
{
    this.SomeCommandCanExecute = false;
}

private string mReason = "Some Command Can Execute";
public string Reason
{
    get { return mReason; }
    set { SetProperty("Reason", ref mReason, value); }
}
```

And then in your View:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
                ToolTip="{Binding Reason}"
                Content="Some Command"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reason}"
                   ToolTip="{Binding Reason}" />
   </StackPanel>
```

Note that you won't see the ToolTip on the disabled button when CanExecute is set to false, which is why I added the TextBlock to show it.  You *will* see the ToolTip on the TextBlock.

Comment: Are you missing the DataContext binding of the TextBlock to the Button?

Comment: No.  This is an MVVM implementation, which assumes that the DataContext of the entire View is bound to an instance of the ViewModel.  SomeCommand and Reason are both properties of that (bound) ViewModel.  In this example, the Button and TextBlock are independant controls - the TextBlock shown here could be a TextBox, or a Button, or a ____ - it is just used to show the bound property (especially since you cannot see the ToolTip on the disabled Button).

Comment: No, I am sorry to disagree with you, but your implementation would result in every command having the same reason.

Comment: Sorry - from your question, I didn't realize that you wanted to have multiple reasons.  Even so, you could easily use a CommandParameter to set an appropriate reason for multiple occurrances of the same command.